# What methods can I use to reduce such a visible seam?

Tags: texturing, uv

I never noticed this seam on my rocks till I decided to modify the main texture for them to emit light from some of the low spots. This is a texture on all 6 sides of a cube, and subdivided a few times.

What methods are available to reduce the visibility of this seam?

[image]

Edit: Looks like I use texture painting to do what I need! Only issue is is that some sort of symmetry mode is on where both sides of the seam mirror each other.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 methods worth looking into.

- [Blended box mapping](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/nodes/textures.html#image-texture) (cycles / rendering only)
  *Easy to enable and apply everywhere but adds noticeable blurring/blending.*
- Projection painting - use the clone tool in 3d to clone over the seam
  *Gives a lot of control but makes the texture specific to meshes UV's, and wont work for tiling textures. However it can be used anywhere UV textures are supported - exporting to game engines for eg.*

Comment: When you linked blend box mapping, how can I use that? I currently use cycles with texture nodes with my object UV mapped. What can I add that would reduce/remove the visible seams?

Comment: Edit to above: What can I add that would reduce/remove the visible seams? I played with the mapping node with little effect.

Painting worked to reduce the emission seams, though I can't seem to paint over the seams for the main texture. The painting does not seem to respond well on the seams, and sometimes mirrors across them (This is a tiled texture on what used to be a square).